# Do I have to regenerate new SHA-1 keys for a salvaged android map app?

Tags: android, google-maps

I had a huge computer crash a few days ago and when I came to check my back-ups I found that they had mostly been corrupted for some reason. However, I have managed to salvage most of my android app map source code files, which are basically the java files, assets, images, layouts and AndroidManifest files, so I think I can recreate the project with a little work. I have none of the files in my keystore though.

However, there are a few things that concern me. From what I remember, when you create a project afresh, SHA-1 keys are created in app > src > debug > res > values > google_maps_api.xml and app > src > release > res > values > google_maps_api.xml. It looks like I am going to have to create a new project, with the same name, package name etc. as the old one and import the salvaged files into it. I don't think this will be a problem.

I already have the SHA-1 keys for pre-crash debug and release versions in my google developers console. Do I have to use brand new SHA-1 keys and put them in my developer console (under my project API key) or can I use the old ones?

The other problem I was thinking of was when I upload my signed app to the google play store, I am prompted for a password. However, the contents of my keystore directory have gone, but I remember the password I used to create the key for the signed app upload. How can I proceed with this?

Many apologies for the lack of proper terminology or clarity, I've only created one app and I'm having to rely on notes I made at the time and sometimes the technical jargon confuses me.

Edit: for clarity; when I say "prompted for a password", what I meant was compiling the app to create a signed apk for upload to the playstore

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup to your crypto key files (not just the SHA1 fingerprint of them) for the project then you should be able to put the old ones in the same location and keep using that. Android Studio is also able to import / use keystore files from another location.

If all you have are SHA1 fingerprints though, you'll need to regenerate keys indeed.

For your reference, the Android Developer's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) states:

> The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the
>   IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in
>   $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key
>   passwords.

Likewise, the Android SDK tools generate a release certificate when you first do a release build as per Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#fingerprint).

Hope this helps you.